# Holding peak of a sensor value

Tags: c++, c

I am working on my college project which need to **detect the maximum value** coming from temperature sensor. I want to show it continuously and that **value should change only if the next value is higher than the previous value** otherwise it should hold the last max value.

```
int value=0, peak=0,check=0;
value=adcread(0); //reading value from sensor
check=value;  //copying sensor value to a variable
if(check>peak)  //checking if sensor value is greater than peak then update the peak
peak=check;
printf("%d",check);
```

It is always showing the same peak value as the sensor value.
This code is not working please tell me what is wrong in this.
Thanks

Comment: Look at which value you're printing. Then look again until you see the problem.

Comment: If you want to remember previous peak value, you can't use local variable. It must be static or global

Comment: the variable `check` can be completely eliminated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `peak` is a local variable in automatic storage, whose value is always initialized to zero. This causes two problems:

- `peak` will never update for negative values if sensor result can be negative, and
- `peak` will be initialized to zero each time that you go through a function.

To fix this, change declaration of `peak` as follows:

```
static int peak = INT_MIN;
```

This moves `peak` to static storage from automatic storage, meaning that the variable would preserve its value across invocations.

You need to include `<limits.h>` in order for this to compile.

Comment: this statement: `This is because peak is a local variable in automatic storage, whose value is always initialized to zero.`  is wrong, local variables will contain what ever trash happens to be on the stack.   However, a global/static variable is (by default) initialized to 0.

Comment: @user3629249 What do you mean, OP has an explicit initializer setting it to zero.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, perhaps I misread the statement,  There is specific code to initialize the local variable, but I read it as your would 'automatically' be initialized to zero.

Answer (score 0):

got to say that `STATIC INT PEAK;` is the only answer to store the previous value. Just use the following:

```
int value;
static int peak;
value = adcread(0);
if (value){
peak = value;printf(%d,peak);/// this will return the value of adcread everytime it updates
}
print(%d, peak);//once the temp-sensor is off the last value will be shown by it.
```